# How do you get available Iteration Paths from Azure DevOps Services REST API?

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

I cannot find how to retrieve the iterations Paths from the API. I was able to get the parent paths but not child paths.

Tried with below `Get` command. It is giving just parent iterations but not a child.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/classificationnodes?$depth={$depth}&api-version=5.0
```

I'm using powershell.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to get child paths, try using:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/{team}/_apis/work/teamsettings/iterations?api-version=5.1
```

`{team}` is not required. You can check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/work/iterations/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) for more details.

**More details:**

1.Assuming I have such Iterations:

[image]

2.Use this `Get` request in postman to test:

```
https://dev.azure.com/MyOrgName/MyProjectName/_apis/work/teamsettings/iterations?api-version=5.1
```

3.The response will list all child Iterations like this:

[image]

Comment: Receiving empty iteration list with above GET API. Deleted all the iterations and then created new iterations from scratch.

Comment: `AspNetCoreTwoOne` is my project name. You need to replace it with yours.

Comment: Yup, Receiving same results with `https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/{teamId}/_apis/work/teamsettings/iterations`.

Comment: You should firstly make sure you have child iterations in project settings=>project configuration. And check the format in my step2, that's what i used and it can work. (I didn't use the teamID actually)

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but the issue is likely that the url contains a `$` which needs to be escaped with a ` in powersell so it doesn't get interpreted as the start of a variable name.